# How to create addEdge function?

Tags: c++, graph

I am trying to create an addEdge function for a list of train stations and their stops. I have the beginning but am not sure where to go from there. Within the addEdge function I have to search to see if the train station (key) is already in the adjacency list and add it to the list if not. Here is what I have so far along with my comments:

```
#pragma once

#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>

using std::ifstream;
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;
using std::list;
using std::map;
using std::string;
using std::getline;
using std::stoi;
using std::vector;
using std::find;
using std::cout;


// Edge info
struct SodorRoute
{
    string origin;
    string destination;
    string railway;
    unsigned int distance;
};

// An adjacency-list based graph
class SodorNetwork
{
public:
    // Don't need constructor, vector is intially properly empty
    
    // I am stuck here at this function  
    virtual void addEdge(const string& from, const string& to, const string& railway, unsigned int distance)
    {
        
        // - Check to see if each rail station already in adjanceny list; add if not
        // - Add the edge information (a SodorRoute instance) to the list for the connection in the correct places
        // Maybe use std::map function to check for key in list?
    }
```

Comment: Focus. There is some big project you are working on, and to complete the next step you need to "search to see if the train station (key) is already in the adjacency list". Focus your question on that one aspect, and strip out unnecessary context. Then shift to a more abstract perspective. Instead of "train station", you have "key". Instead of "adjacency list", you have.... some kind of vector? (Your `SodorNetwork` class definition does not include any data members, but there is that comment mentioning "vector".)

Comment: At the very least we'd need some info about how you exactly store the info; currently there's just a comment mentioning `vector` which is unlikely to be the only type (except for `SodorRoute`) being used for storing the information.